question about production optimization
the question is,
if Q = AK^a(HL)^b
and the parameters are:

(A =100)  (K = 10000$)  (H = 1)  (L = 100 person)  (a = 0.5) (b = 0.5)

P = 5 per unit, R = interest rate of 3 percent per year , W = 3 per person
the question is :

how much value added because of this production process?
is the level of production already efficient?
how much L should be used, so that the production process can be efficient?

does anyone know any clues on how to answer the value added and the efficient level of production?
